# Create Google Analytics User-Id reporting view through Management API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The title says it all...

While I can create a user-id reporting view through the [Visual Interface in GA](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en#setup), I was wondering if there's anyway for me to do it from the [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3)

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: Haha, yep... I'm not that kind of dev: I wouldn't be coming here before spending some considerable time doing research of my own

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible via API, you can consider send userId as a custom dimension instead, which can be safely configured (and in my experience it provides a better result).

Comment: Hello there... The reporting API seems to be great for working with the data after user interactions. 

However, I need something for the setup of GA properties. We basically setup new websites everyday, and they all have the same views and settings. That's why I'm going with the API to automate the process. 

I need to be able to create a new property in a GA account, and have user-id reporting enabled for some views. I can't use GAs auto-generated user id.

Comment: I didn't understand you were referring to the setup instead of the report. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is a good idea... One problem that comes to mind is that this approach might make GA analysts lives a bit harder, since the same user can belong to different Client IDs, requiring them to jump between many users in order to get all the data related to a single actual user. Thank you for the idea nevertheless